# Getting a probability from a classifier

Tags: matlab, computer-vision

I'm doing some work classifying images and was looking for a classifier that gives its answer in turns of a probability instead of true/false like svmclassify. Anyone have any suggestions for toolboxes that have this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RVMs' (Relevant Vector Machines) output probability and if you want to use them, download Kevin Murphy's Machine Learning toolkit. Matlab doesn't have an RVM implementation as far as I know.